# Pandas - Stack dataframes with different name and number of columns on top of each other

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a csv log from two dataframes that are entirely different from each other, so I cannot just simply concat/merge. The first dataframe is just one row of datapoints with MORE columns than the second dataframe, while the second dataframe has a bunch of rows of datapoints. I would like to also add a blank row between them to add some clarity. Is there a way to put them together in such way that for the second dataframe the blank cells get an NaN value?

Consider the simplified example below:

Dataframe 1:

```
    Col A  Col B  Col C  Col D  Col E
0    XYZ    452   GHJ    089     IUT
```

Dataframe 2:

```
    Data1  Data2  Data3  Data4
0   1234   4567   7890   6543      
1   8765   4565   8767   0987
..
n   4387   0943   4598   3212
```

Ouput:

```
    Col A  Col B  Col C  Col D  Col E
0    XYZ    452   GHJ    089     IUT     
1    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
2    1234   4567  7890   6543    NaN
3    8765   4565  8767   0987    NaN
..
n    4387   0943  4598   3212    NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Targeting your requirement.

1. mash columns of second dataframe to be same as wide first one so you don't go wide
2. then `concat()` them inserting a new dataframe between which is a dummy `np.nan` against first column in first dataframe

```
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Col A":["XYZ"],"Col B":[452],"Col C":[" GHJ"],"Col D":[89],"Col E":[" IUT"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Data1":[1234,8765,4387],"Data2":[4567,4565,943],"Data3":[7890,8767,4598],"Data4":[6543,987,3212]})
df2.columns=[df1.columns[i] for i,c in enumerate(df2.columns) if i<len(df1.columns)]

pd.concat([
    df1,
    pd.DataFrame({df1.columns[0]:[np.nan]}),
    df2
])
```

**output**

```
Col A   Col B Col C   Col D Col E
  XYZ   452.0   GHJ    89.0   IUT
  NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
 1234  4567.0  7890  6543.0   NaN
 8765  4565.0  8767   987.0   NaN
 4387   943.0  4598  3212.0   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I like how easy it is to read the concat and figure out you are adding the empty dataframe, in case someone in the future wants to remove/add on that.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) along `axis=1` to conform the columns of `df2` with the columns of `df1`, then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with optional parameter `ignore_index=True` to concat it with dataframe `df1`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True),
                df2.set_axis(df1.columns[:df2.shape[1]], axis=1)], ignore_index=True)
```

Result:

```
print(df)
  Col A   Col B Col C   Col D Col E
0   XYZ   452.0   GHJ    89.0   IUT
1   NaN     NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
2  1234  4567.0  7890  6543.0   NaN
3  8765  4565.0  8767   987.0   NaN
4  4387   943.0  4598  3212.0   NaN
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, as good as the accepted one, there's a lot I can learn from your answer. I just went with which one came first as a way of being fair.

Comment: @bloo No worries, Happy coding ;).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach which you can try:

```
m = df1.iloc[:,:df2.shape[1]].append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)
out = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((m,df2)),columns=m.columns).join(df1.iloc[:,df2.shape[1]:])
```

---

```
print(out)

  Col A Col B Col C Col D Col E
0   XYZ   452   GHJ    89   IUT
1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  1234  4567  7890  6543   NaN
3  8765  4565  8767   987   NaN
......
......
```

Approach taken:

- Slice the first dataframe according to the `shape[1]` of the second and add an empty row
- using `np.vstack` create a stacked array and call the dataframe constructor
- name columns as the first slice since we want columns names from 1st dataframe
- join the remaining columns to the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it in one line:

`df = pd.concat([df1.rename({x: i for i, x in enumerate(df1.columns)}, axis=1), df2.rename({x: i for i, x in enumerate(df2.columns)}, axis=1)]).rename({i: x for i, x in enumerate(df1.columns)}, axis=1)`

The code splits up like this:

- Rename the columns of both dataframes to 0 -> len(columns)
- Concatenate the dataframes
- Rename the columsn to those of first dataframe

I'd personally split it into steps:

```
df1_renamed = df1.rename({x: i for i, x in enumerate(df1.columns)}, axis=1)
df2_renamed = df2.rename({x: i for i, x in enumerate(df2.columns)}, axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df1_renamed, df2_renamed])
df.rename({i: x for i, x in enumerate(df1.columns)}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```